# How to read data based on dates from Cloud Firestore

Tags: android, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I'm new to Cloud Firestore, using Android studio to develop an app and I was wondering how should I read the data that I have entered based on the Date where I entered it and then have the app to read the data which is the same date as I entered it?
The problem is that I can't get the app to read the "Dates" from the database as the app will display "null" as a result.

This is the image of my Cloud Firestore:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/e06HW.jpg

MainActivity.java

```
db.collection("Meditation")
                        .document(timeStamp)
                        .set(user)
                        .addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<Void>() {
                            @Override
                            public void onSuccess(Void aVoid) {

                            }
                        })
                        .addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
                                Log.w(TAG, "Error adding document",e);
                            }
                        });
                startActivity(intent);
```

SecondActivity.java

```
private void readMeditationDay() {

        DocumentReference readOne = db.collection("Meditation")
                .document(timeStamp);

                readOne.get().addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<DocumentSnapshot>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<DocumentSnapshot> task) {
                        if (task.isSuccessful()){
                            DocumentSnapshot doc = task.getResult();
                            StringBuilder data = new StringBuilder("");
                            data.append("Status: ").append(doc.getString("Status"));
                            data.append("\nFeedback: ").append(doc.getString("Feedback"));
                            data.append("\nDuration (Minutes): ").append(doc.getString("Time"));
                            txtDisplay.setText(data.toString());
                        }
                    }
                });
    }
```

I'm very new to reading database especially Firestore so a little advice / help would be appreciated Thanks! :3

Comment: first please check 'timeStamp' variable is same as your document in firestore pls debug by adding logs

Comment: String timeStamp = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy.MM.dd.HH.mm.ss").format(new java.util.Date());
this is my timeStamp for both activities

Comment: this is giving you current timeStamp which is different for both the activities, that's why the you are writing on diff. time and reading on diff. time, You have to take same timeStamp for both activities

Comment: What's the value of `timeStamp` inside `.document(timeStamp)`?

Comment: I've check your document structure from the link (https://imgur.com/Yl8avI2). 
Your document format is without second value.
Change your string timestamp with this format SimpleDateFormat("yyyy.MM.dd.HH.mm")